# How to use an alias in a subquery in the SELECT clause ? postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, subquery

First of all, thank you for your time!

I have migrated my database from MariaDB to PostgreSQL and now some of my queries don't work anymore.

Here is an example :

```
SELECT DISTINCT table.column AS columnAlias,
          SUM(table2.column)/(SELECT COUNT(table.column) 
                              FROM table 
                              WHERE table.column= columnAlias) 
FROM ...
```

The problem is that this SQL query worked well when my database was a MariaDB database, but actually, I had to migrate it to a PostgreSQL one, and now it throws an

`ERROR: 42703: column "columnAlias" does not exists`.

I think the problem is that PostgreSQL doesn't accept the alias in a subquery, but have you an idea of how to fix that? or another way to make the job done?

Thank you for your time,

Guillaume.

Comment: The Postgresql error here is according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Comment: `... FROM table t2 WHERE t2.column= table.column)`

Comment: @jarlh I have tried this solution, but that change the result of my query, it doesn't return a percentage but only a flat value which I can't convert to a percentage later...

Comment: @RiggsFolly I promise you it make sense in my case but I can't send you the whole query with reals table names due to confidentiality issues :/ but thanks I'm gonna add the quotes my alias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.columnAlias,
                SUM(table2.column) / (SELECT COUNT(table.column)
                                       FROM table WHERE table.column= v.columnAlias)
FROM ... CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (table.column)) v(columnAlias)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! that perfectly fixed my problem !